# Bootloader freezes on login screen when booting into Lion from Boot Camp

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp

Every time I reboot from Boot Camp into OS X, the bootloader gets to the login screen, and then after I've entered my username and password, the screen will just go grey. I have to force a restart with the power button, and then when I reboot, it proceeds normally.

Specifics: Windows 7 Professional 32-bit in Boot Camp, and OS X 10.7.1. The same issue happened with 10.7.0. This is on a late-2008 MacBook Pro 15".

Comment: do you have Sophos Antivirus installed?

Comment: Is this still and issue? If so, what version of OS X are you running now?

Comment: Not happened for some time now, don't know what actually fixed it. I'm now on 10.7.3, and yes i do have sophos installed

Comment: Try updating to Lion 10.7.5

Answer (score 1):

This suggestion seems to helps a lot with all sorts of things, so I figured I'd suggest it here just in case.

Go to your Disk Utility app and press the following buttons in the numbered order. I would recommend only doing 1, 2, and 3, but if this doesn't help with the problem, you can also try to run 1(b) from Recovery Mode (or while running your computer off an external hard 
drive) because it won't work while you're logged on.

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, i can't check anymore as i don't use Boot Camp, and i've long since dumped the mac that i was using.

Comment: My bad ;) I keep forgetting to check posting dates before I reply haha.  Well, good luck anyway! :)

Comment: Have an upvote anyway. :)