# Macbook Pro hangs when booting into Boot Camp Windows 7

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, startup, performance

I have a 2011 Macbook Pro 15" 10.7.4 with Windows 7 installed in Boot Camp. A few days ago, I tried to boot into Windows 7 and it just froze after I selected the Boot Camp volume on the Select Drive screen and the processor fan went into overdrive. This now happens every time. The only way to make it functional is to force-power-off and restart in OS X.

I don't understand what's happening - Windows 7 works fine when I use it via Parallels, but won't boot to the metal.

I've tried resetting the SMC and PRAM but nothing seems to work. This is extra frustrating because I need to use Windows for work.

I looked here, but it's no help:

[Bootloader freezes on login screen when booting into Lion from Boot Camp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24317/bootloader-freezes-on-login-screen-when-booting-into-lion-from-boot-camp)

Comment: That'll be a 'no', then...

Comment: I ran into the same issue today. I am assuming that some sort of Windows update is the culprit. However, since I can no longer boot into Windows in any way, not sure how it will get resolved...

Comment: I'm also suffering from this problem. The moment I click on the bootcamp disk icon the whole machine just freezes. All I can do is hold down the on/off button until it shuts down. Oddly enough, I have Fusion on the machine, and I can load my bootcamp partition through Fusion with no issues. It just won't do it from the disk selection screen.

Comment: Are you still having this issue?  If so, does the problem still never happen when you restart in OS X?

Answer (score 2):

If you get a copy of Paragon NTFS for Mac you can do a disk repair for NTFS volumes. The software has a 10 day trial and a license is about $20. NTFS for Mac also serves as a driver for full access to NTFS volumes which is superior to the limited Read only access of NTFS volumes built into Macs. If you are a regular user of both Mac and Windows its worth the investment.

Once installed the program is accessible from System Preferences. For the problem described above you need to first unmount the volumes "System Reserve" and "BootCamp". Then remount the volumes and run verify on each volume.

[image: System Preferences with NTFS for Mac at bottom left]
[image: Volumes settings]

Answer (score 0):

I have a 27" iMac running Windows 7 Boot Camp and 10.10. I've occasionally had problems like this.

Usually I can resolve it by booting to the Mac OS and running Disk Utility disk repair on both the Volume and OS X Partition. It would be nice if you could do it on your PC partition as well, but such is life.

Another thing you might want to check is your Console. Do a search for any I/O Errors. I had serious issues a while back with strange slowdowns on my Mac side, only to find that my PC partition was corrupted and every time the Mac looked at it (through spotlight or such), it hiccuped.

I'm guessing you're using the whole Boot Camp-Parallels thing from your statement? Or is that a separate virtual machine?